# physicshelperxaml revolve

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, physics-engine, farseer

I am a beginner so please bear with me.
I am using the physics helper XAML library ([Farseer](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/)) to use physics inside my app.

Currently, I am having issues with the following

1. Having a object in particular a triangle revolve around a single point, while having its vertices point at the circular joint.
2. Also after I got the triangle to revolve(without the vertices pointing) when the it reaches an angular velocity of `0.016`, the object then start to jitter a lot.

Please guys can someone help me with this issue? I am on the edge of sanity after spending so many hours behind this.
It seems and should be fairly simple, but yet evades me